# How to run Fn + Esc keyboard combo automatically at startup?

Tags: scripts, startup

Every time I log in to ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS, my Fn button is toggled to OFF state. So, when I want to change volume, I need to do <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> and after that I can use my laptop normally. The thing is that the <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> move which I commit every time after I log in irritates me. Is there any way to make <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> combination automatically, maybe launching some script? My laptop is Asus P3540FA.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you can do this with any operating system - the Fn key is hardwired to your hardware and is not "seen" by the operating system.

Look into the settings of your computer's BIOS. There is most likely a setting to indicated how the function keys should work by default.